# How to use custom translation hub for Microsoft Translator Widget?

Tags: azure, translation

I found the information [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/widget.aspx) says:

> The Widget also fully supports prepublishing customized translation, using the *Translator Hub*.

However, I couldn't find any document about how to use the customized translation.
And another document also states that [it supports Hub Customization](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/features.aspx)

From the [translater widget page](http://www.bing.com/widget/translator), there doesn't seem any special parameter from the generated url except `siteData`, for which there were few OS questions about it but no answer yet. Hope someone could point the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually found out a way to use custom translator hub in widget url. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn133609.aspx) mentioned how to get the `category` id out from the custom translator hub. It is under the Request Deployment step in your training project. And [another document for the translator widget](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn735968.aspx) mentioned the `category` parameter in the url. Interestingly the `sitedata` is actually not relevant.